# How to configure vercel.json when using vue3 + serverless API

Tags: vuejs3, serverless, vercel

My vue3 app is deployed on vercel, and uses vercel serverless functions.

I found when refreshing on page other than `/`, it would throw a 404,  and research said I needed a `vercel.json` that maps all requests to the root:

```
{
  "rewrites": [{ "source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/" }]
}
```

This fixed the refresh problem, but broke all my APIs that are in `/api/*`

So I tried this:

```
{
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/api/(.*)",
      "destination": "/api"
    },
    {
      "source": "/(.*)",
      "destination": "/"
    }
  ]
}
```

Which broke everything fully. Trying to figure out the right config and need help <3

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
{
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "/((?!api).*)",
      "destination": "/"
    }
  ]
}
```